# Basic template for beginning a C program

Tags: c, strings, unit-testing

I developed a basic template for beginning a C program. It attempts to implement the following:

1. Memory allocation and error handling
2. Message logging
3. Safer string copying
4. Safer string concatenation
5. Test framework
6. Error handling

How does it look?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Macros for constants*/
#define INIT_BUF_SIZE 10000
#define MAX_INT_STR_LEN 20

/*Function-like macros*/
#define MALLOC(newbuf, bufsize, logbuf) if ((rc = str_malloc(newbuf, bufsize, \
        logbuf)) != SUCCESS) return rc
#define CAT(dest, source, logbuf) if ((rc = str_cat(dest, source, \
        logbuf)) != SUCCESS) return rc
#define TESTCASE(func, logbuf, testcount) if ((rc = func(logbuf)) != SUCCESS) \
                                                    return rc; testcount++
/*Return codes*/
typedef enum {
  SUCCESS,
  ERR_STR_COPY,
  ERR_STR_CAT,
  ERR_STR_MALLOC,
  ERR_RC_NOT_SET } td_rc;

/*Dynamically allocated string with allocated size */
struct strbuff{
  size_t size;
  char *str;
};

/*Function prototypes*/

/*Convenience wrapper around malloc with optional log parameter*/
td_rc str_malloc(struct strbuff *newbuf, size_t bufsize, 
    struct strbuff *logbuf);
/*Safer replacement for strcpy with optional log parameter*/
td_rc str_copy(struct strbuff *dest, char *source, struct strbuff *logbuf);
/*Safer replacement for strcat with optional log parameter*/
td_rc str_cat(struct strbuff *dest, char *source, struct strbuff *logbuf);
/*Test runner*/
td_rc test_all(struct strbuff *logbuf);
/*Test cases*/
td_rc test_str_malloc(struct strbuff *logbuf);
td_rc test_str_copy(struct strbuff *logbuf);
td_rc test_str_cat(struct strbuff *logbuf);

/*Output HTTP header and log messages*/
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  td_rc rc = ERR_RC_NOT_SET;
  struct strbuff logbuf;
  MALLOC(&logbuf, INIT_BUF_SIZE, NULL);
  logbuf.size = INIT_BUF_SIZE;
  if ((rc = str_copy(&logbuf, "content-type: text/html\n\n", NULL)) 
      == SUCCESS) {
    if (argc > 1)
      if (strcmp(argv[1], "test") == 0)
        /*If the first parameter is "test", run all test cases*/
        rc = test_all(&logbuf);
    printf("%s", logbuf.str);
  }
  free(logbuf.str);
  return rc;
}

td_rc str_malloc(struct strbuff *newbuf, size_t bufsize, 
    struct strbuff *logbuf){
  td_rc rc = ERR_RC_NOT_SET;
  newbuf->str = malloc(sizeof *newbuf->str * bufsize);
  if (!newbuf->str) {
    /*If malloc fails, write error to log if supplied
      otherwise write to standard output*/
    char errmes[100];
    sprintf(errmes, "malloc failed : size requested %lu \n", 
        (unsigned long)bufsize); 
    if (!logbuf)
      printf("%s", errmes);
    else CAT(logbuf, errmes, NULL);
    return ERR_STR_MALLOC;
  }
  /*Terminate the new empty string*/
  *newbuf->str = '\0';
  newbuf->size = bufsize;
  return SUCCESS;
} 

td_rc str_copy(struct strbuff *dest, char *source, struct strbuff *logbuf){
  size_t sourcelen = strlen(source);
  td_rc rc = ERR_RC_NOT_SET;
  /**dest should have been initialized with str_malloc*/
  if (sourcelen > dest->size) {
    /*If if the source string is longer than the destion buffer, 
     * write error to log if supplied otherwise write to standard output*/
    char errmes[100];
    sprintf(errmes, "string copy failed : source length %lu > \
        dest allocated space %lu\n", (unsigned long)sourcelen, \
        (unsigned long)dest->size); 
    if (!logbuf)
      printf("%s", errmes);
    else CAT(logbuf, errmes, NULL);
    return ERR_STR_COPY;
  }
  memcpy(dest->str, source, sourcelen+1);
  return SUCCESS;
} 

td_rc str_cat(struct strbuff *dest, char *source, struct strbuff *logbuf){
  td_rc rc = ERR_RC_NOT_SET;
  /**dest should have been initialized with str_malloc*/
  size_t destlen = strlen(dest->str);
  size_t destfree = dest->size - destlen;
  size_t sourcelen = strlen(source);
  if (sourcelen > destfree) {
    /*If the source string is longer than the free space in the 
     * destination buffer, write error to log if supplied otherwise write 
     * to standard output*/
    char errmes[100];
    sprintf(errmes, "string concatenation failed : source length %lu > \
        dest free space %lu\n", (unsigned long)sourcelen, \
        (unsigned long)destfree); 
    rc = ERR_STR_CAT;
    if (!logbuf)
      printf("%s", errmes);
    else 
      rc = str_cat(logbuf, errmes, NULL);
  } else { 
    memcpy(dest->str+destlen, source, sourcelen+1);
    rc = SUCCESS;
  }
  return rc;
} 

td_rc test_all(struct strbuff *logbuf){
  td_rc rc = ERR_RC_NOT_SET;
  int testcount = 0;
  char rc_str[MAX_INT_STR_LEN];
  /*If a test case fails, stop further processing and output the log, 
   * otherwise output a test summary*/
  TESTCASE(test_str_malloc, logbuf, testcount);
  TESTCASE(test_str_copy, logbuf, testcount);
  TESTCASE(test_str_cat, logbuf, testcount);
  sprintf(rc_str, "%d", testcount);
  CAT(logbuf, "\n", NULL);
  CAT(logbuf, rc_str, NULL);
  CAT(logbuf, " tests completed successfully\n", NULL);
  return SUCCESS;
}

td_rc test_str_malloc(struct strbuff* logbuf){
  td_rc rc = ERR_RC_NOT_SET;
  struct strbuff teststr;
  MALLOC(&teststr, 5, logbuf);
  if (teststr.size == 5)
    rc = SUCCESS;
  else rc = ERR_STR_MALLOC;
  free(teststr.str);
  return rc;
}

td_rc test_str_copy(struct strbuff* logbuf){
  td_rc rc = ERR_RC_NOT_SET;
  struct strbuff teststr;
  MALLOC(&teststr, 7, logbuf);
  if ((rc = str_copy(&teststr, "foo", logbuf)) == SUCCESS) {
    if (strcmp(teststr.str, "foo")) 
      rc = ERR_STR_COPY;
    else {
      if ((rc = str_copy(&teststr, "bar", logbuf)) == SUCCESS) {
        if (strcmp(teststr.str, "bar")) 
          rc = ERR_STR_COPY;
      }
    }
  }
  free(teststr.str);
  return rc;
}

td_rc test_str_cat(struct strbuff* logbuf){
  td_rc rc = ERR_RC_NOT_SET;
  struct strbuff teststr;
  MALLOC(&teststr, 7, logbuf);
  if ((rc = str_cat(&teststr, "foo", logbuf)) == SUCCESS) {
    if (strcmp(teststr.str, "foo")) 
      rc = ERR_STR_CAT;
    else {
      if ((rc = str_cat(&teststr, "bar", logbuf)) == SUCCESS) {
        if (strcmp(teststr.str, "foobar")) 
          rc = ERR_STR_CAT;
      }
    }
  }
  free(teststr.str);
  return rc;
}
```

Comment: Are you limiting code to pre-C99?

Comment: @chux, I want the template to be as portable as possible and I understood the ANSI C runtime library was the _lingua franca_ provided by most systems, OSes, devices, etc. Having said that, if other runtime library functions such as snprintf are effectively universally available, I could use them too.

Comment: Consider there is no version that is a universal subset of C - C evolves.  Any sub-language selection will carry pros and cons.  I recommend a C99 target with maybe some limitations.  See [MS Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28118893/2410359) C99 support.

Answer (score 8):

I would say that you've got a case of "solution in search of a problem" here — and your solutions are mostly faulty!

---

```
#define MALLOC(newbuf, bufsize, logbuf) if ((rc = str_malloc(newbuf, bufsize, \
        logbuf)) != SUCCESS) return rc
```

Look up "hygienic macros." The problem with a macro definition like this one here is that it'll do the wrong thing if the programmer writes

```
if (useSmallBuffer)
  MALLOC(mybuf, 100, logbuf);
else
  MALLOC(mybuf, 200, logbuf);
```

(Expand it out. Do you see why the control flow goes wrong?)

Whenever you write a "statement-like" macro in C or C++, you *must* wrap it in `do { ... } while (0)` for hygiene.

Also, consider what happens with

```
int ra = 1, rb = 2, rc = 3;
MALLOC(mybuf, 3, logbuf);
mybuf[0] = ra;
mybuf[1] = rb;
mybuf[2] = rc;
```

Macros generally should not take "hidden" or "implicit" parameters.

---

```
/*Macros for constants*/
#define INIT_BUF_SIZE 10000
#define MAX_INT_STR_LEN 20
```

These macros' names are unnecessarily cryptic, and their purpose is obscure. Why do you need them at all?

The only place you use `INIT_BUF_SIZE` is in `main` —

```
MALLOC(&logbuf, INIT_BUF_SIZE, NULL);
logbuf.size = INIT_BUF_SIZE;
```

— which means that *at least* its scope should be restricted to `main`.

```
const size_t initial_logbuf_size = 10000;
MALLOC(&logbuf, initial_logbuf_size, NULL);
logbuf.size = initial_logbuf_size;
```

The next thing we notice about this snippet is that we're setting `logbuf.size = K` immediately after a call to `MALLOC(&logbuf, k, ...)`. This smells awfully like we've trying to preserve some invariant here — such as, "`foo.size` always contains the malloc'ed length of the buffer `foo`." We should move the code that preserves that invariant into the `MALLOC` macro.

```
#define MALLOC(newbuf, bufsize, logbuf) \
do { \
    int rc = str_malloc(newbuf, bufsize, logbuf); \
    if (rc != SUCCESS) return rc; \
    (newbuf)->size = (bufsize); \
} while (0)
```

Notice that I placed parentheses around the macro arguments `(newbuf)` and `(bufsize)` when I used them inside the macro itself.

---

Working on that macro, something caught my eye. We now have some logic (`(newbuf)->size = (bufsize);`) placed *after* the early `return` statement. And we're using raw pointers (instead of something like C++'s `unique_ptr<T>`) to manage our memory. This smells like a recipe for a memory leak! But of course the same smell was there before this change; it was just masked by the unnecessary complexity of the code. Consider:

```
void foo() {
    int rc = 0;
    struct strbuff buffer1, buffer2;
    MALLOC(&buffer1, 1000, NULL);  // possible early return
    MALLOC(&buffer2, 1000, NULL);  // possible early return
    free(buffer1.str);
    free(buffer2.str);
}
```

If the underlying `malloc` of `buffer2` fails and returns `NULL`, then the buffer pointed to by `buffer1` will be leaked!

To deal with the freeing of resources in case of early return, C programmers usually use a pattern like `goto cleanup;` — see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215449/memory-cleanup-in-functions-with-many-return-points) or [Apple's famous "goto fail" bug](https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/apple-goto-fail.html).

---

Any time I'm looking at C code, I look specifically at how they handle their buffers: Are they correctly passing around buffer lengths to avoid buffer overflows? This doesn't necessarily mean using silly helper functions like `strcpy_s`; it just means not doing anything terribly dumb.

So when I see `sprintf`, in code that is *specifically intended* to help protect against buffer overflows, it sets off alert bells:

```
char errmes[100];
sprintf(errmes, "string concatenation failed : source length %lu > \
    dest free space %lu\n", (unsigned long)sourcelen, \
    (unsigned long)destfree);
```

Now, at first glance, the longest possible string we could be printing into the buffer `errmes` here is `"string concatenation failed : source length 4000000000 > dest free space 4000000000\n"`, which is only 84 characters long. So that's cool, right? We've got 15 bytes of "fudge" left over! No problem! We therefore resist the angel on our shoulder pleading with us to use the correct buffer-overflow-proof construction,

```
char errmes[100];
snprintf(errmes, sizeof errbuf, "string concatenation failed : source length %lu > \
    dest free space %lu\n", (unsigned long)sourcelen, \
    (unsigned long)destfree);
```

Go away, angel!

But **"fudge" has a way of being wrong**, or at least fragile. Suppose a year from now you went back and changed this code to

```
char errmes[100];
sprintf(errmes, "WARNING: string concatenation failed : source length %lu > \
    dest free space %lu\n", (unsigned long)sourcelen, \
    (unsigned long)destfree);
```

Here we've added 9 bytes to the string: `"WARNING: "` (don't forget that extra space we added!). We add it all up again and determine that the maximum length of the string is now 84+9 = 93 bytes. No problem.

Except that **where there's one bug, there's usually two.** Bugs are caused by carelessness, and carelessness isn't a one-time occurrence. Look again at the line above. How many characters are *really* in that string?

Did you spot the trailing backslash that marks a *line continuation?* The format string in your original code actually looks like this:

```
"string concatenation failed : source length %lu >         dest free space %lu\n"
```

It's 8 bytes longer than we thought it was! So with `"WARNING: "` added, it *does* overflow the buffer, and we get a security exploit.

The general morals of this story are **bolded** above, but here's one more specific moral: *Never ever use backslash-continuation, except in the special case of defining a multi-line macro body.*

---

Finally, let's look at `str_cat` one more time. I'll `//...` out all the parts that don't interest me right now...

```
td_rc str_cat(struct strbuff *dest, char *source, struct strbuff *logbuf){
  //...
  if (sourcelen > destfree) {
    //...
    if (!logbuf)
      printf("%s", errmes);
    else 
      rc = str_cat(logbuf, errmes, NULL);
  } else { 
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

Yes, that's right — you've managed to write a *recursive* string concatenation routine! `str_cat` calls itself!

This means that if there's no room in the buffer to concatenate the input strings, we'll produce an error message and attempt to concatenate it onto the log buffer... and if there's no room in the log buffer, we'll produce an error message and — well, thankfully, the recursive call passes `NULL` instead of a log buffer, so we won't recurse infinitely. That's a small blessing.

Your `logbuf` parameter is essentially an attempt to allow the user to customize your library's error-reporting mechanism. If you're really interested in going down that route, I recommend that you learn about *function pointers*, which would allow you to write a library function like this:

```
typedef void (*error_reporter)(const char *, ...);

td_rc strbuff_plusequals(struct strbuff *dst, struct strbuff src, error_reporter report_error)
{
    const size_t dstlen = strlen(dst->str);
    const size_t srclen = strlen(src.str);
    if (srclen >= dst->size - dstlen) {
        report_error("string concatenation failed: source length %zu > dest free space %zu", srclen, dst->size - dstlen);
        return ERR_STR_CAT;
    } else {
        memcpy(dst->str + dstlen, src.str, srclen + 1);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

struct strbuff strbuff_view(const char *s) {
    return (struct strbuff){ strlen(s), (char *)s };
}

void report(const char *fmt, ...);

int main() {
    struct strbuff s;
    int err = strbuff_create(&s, 100);
    if (err) exit(err);
    err = strbuff_plusequals(&s, strbuff_view("hello"), report);
    if (err) exit(err);
    err = strbuff_plusequals(&s, strbuff_view(" world"), report);
    if (err) exit(err);
    assert(strcmp(s.str, "hello world") == 0);
    strbuff_destroy(s);
}
```

The writing of `strbuff_create` and `strbuff_destroy` is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Another exercise for the reader is to add a `void *cookie` parameter to `report_error`.

---

Anyway, I'd say you should learn about `snprintf` and `strcpy` and so on, before trying to invent your own string-handling library. Start with the tools that are provided to you and get good with *them*, first.

Comment: A very patient and complete answer.

Comment: @chux: I feel like I must say: my answer is *extremely incomplete* compared to all the things I could have said! (And technically I bet I could have been more patient too. ;))

Comment: Agree'd. There is much more - yet complete as much as can be handled at once, IMO.  I hope OP considers many of your fine suggestions and posts again with an improved version.  Then the next level of feedback can occur.

Comment: @Quuxplusone, thanks for your code analysis. I agree with you on the following points - 1. Statement-like macros should be wrapped in `do { ... } while (0)` 2. The macro `MAX_INT_STR_LEN` (maximum length of string containing a 64 bit int) is not useful 3. The statement `logbuf.size = INIT_BUF_SIZE;` should not be in the main function as is it already assigned at the end of the `str_malloc` function 4. The backslashes in the sprintf string were a mistake 5. MALLOC would cause a memory leaks in the case you mentioned because the `return rc` statement would cause `free(logbuf.str);` to be skipped

Comment: @Quuxplusone ... These corrections have been incorporated in my new [version] (https://github.com/pplanner16/C-template/blob/master/template.c) Other points - 1. Most of my apps require basic string and error handling, a test framework and logging. This template is supposed to provide the minimum functionality as a starting point for a real C project. Ideally it should be portable (hence the choice of ANSI C), robust, efficient and simple. 2. `INIT_BUF_SIZE` means "initial buffer size". I defined this macro so that it could be easily found if its value needs to be adjusted.

Comment: @Quuxplusone ... 3. The angel of security who implored me use snprintf was trumped by the the god of portability who said it's not ANSI C. Questions - 1. What is wrong the recursive str_cat? 2. Please explain where the "unnecessary complexity of the code" is. 3. What made you think the logbuf parameter is an attempt to allow the user to customize the library's error-reporting mechanism?

Comment: Unfortunately Quuxplusone has fallen silent after issuing a stern critique of my template program. Can anyone explain why he/she took exception to my recursive str_cat function? Also I used sprintf instead of snprintf because I though the latter was not part of ANSI C (one of my aims is maximum portability). Trailing backslashes aside, was there anything wrong with my usage? Is there a better way? @chux - I am titillated by your suggestion "There is much more", please share

Comment: Okay, okay. Easy one first: `snprintf` is standard C99 and available everywhere I'm aware of. (Notice that `snprintf` is old enough to vote in the U.S. as of this year.) Harder: What's wrong with a recursive `strcat`? Well, it's just *way more complicated than `strcat` needs to be,* that's all. If we must boil it down to a stock phrase, I guess I'd say ["Single Responsibility Principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): your string-concatenation function has taken responsibility not just for string-concatenation but also for integer formatting and I/O to stdout.

Comment: "There is much more" might include things like "putting the tests in the same .o file with the code is unusual," "it's too easy to memory-leak," "logging to stderr is more usual than logging to stdout," "`if`s without braces are the devil" (I thought I mentioned that but I guess it was only in the context of hygienic macros), and even "if you're using `malloc` anyway, why bother keeping track of the current capacity? just call `realloc` before each concatenation and let libc worry about capacity issues."

Comment: *Rationale behind my error and logging implementation*
Return codes are handy when coding the calling function. After calling `tc_rc foo()`, often the following code is suffcient `if ((rc = foo()) == SUCCESS) return rc;` so long as `foo()` frees any memory it may have allocated. However return codes are not handy for providing details on the specific error that occurred. For this reason, I have included an optional `struct strbuff *logbuf` as the last parameter of most of my functions. It is optional because (1) I don't want to force the caller to use it and ...

Comment: ...(2) if `logbuf.str` is full, obviously it can't be used anyway.

What do you think of this approach? Do you have a better suggestion?

Regarding the Single Responsibility Principle, perhaps it would cleaner to put the logic when sourcelen > destfree in its own function - `str_cat_err_proc(strbuff *logbuf)` for example, or did you mean something else?

Comment: @user2309803: To help with both "providing details on the specific error that occurred" *and* "put the logic in its own function", I recommend the `error_reporter` callback technique described in my answer. :)

Comment: @user2309803 You are entering an important architecture step in C programming - error catching/handling/reporting.  The is no universal answer.  The best approach  1) varies depending on coding paradigm and 2) is an important early design decision.  Good luck!

Comment: @Quuxplusone I assume `report_error` is going to concatenate its error message parameters (`const char *, ...`) to a log buffer. In that case, shouldn't `error_reporter` (and `report`) have `strbuff *logbuf` as a parameter?

Comment: I would assume that `report_error` is going to `vfprintf` its parameters onto some log stream, which might be `stderr` or might be something else (see note about the `void *cookie` parameter, and [cf. `qsort_r`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort_r)). But sure, it could write them into a char buffer... or a `wchar_t` buffer... or pack them into a protobuf and send it over some network interface... or whatever it wants. That's the fundamental point of Separation of Responsibilities: it's not `strcat`'s _job_ to decide how errors are handled!

Comment: @Quuxplusone, If I understand correctly, the main benefit of your `error_reporter` call back is that it allows error logging to customized without touching `strbuff_plusequals` Interesting idea but I wasn't planning to have more than one error logging function. What about individual test case functions? Let's say I wanted   function which prints a test result summary. Assuming all test case functions have the same signature, would you advise designing a `test_result_reporter` function whose parameter is function pointer to an individual testcase? ...

Comment: @Quuxplusone .. or the other way round - each testcase function has parameter which is function pointer to test_result_reporter?

Comment: @user2309803: For your `test_*` functions, I would think the most important thing is to clearly distinguish each individual test result as either "red" or "green." Right now you do that by returning `SUCCESS` on "green" and [anything else] on "red." That's fine. But sure, if you wanted to pack a bunch of different tests into the same function, you might pass in a `test_result_reporter` function pointer — honestly I'd just name it `void (*Assert)(bool, const char *msg)`. Or, you might have your function return a `struct results { int passed; int failed; }`, or something like that.

Comment: @Quuxplusone you said _just call realloc before each concatenation and let libc worry about capacity issues_ Do you mean something like `realloc ( buf, strlen(buf) + strlen(string_to_concatenate) + 1)`? That certainly would simplify memory management, but I understood that repeated calls to `realloc` was inefficient - better to allocate an initial block and then keep doubling the size when free space runs out - but the allocated size would still have to be tracked

Comment: @user2309803: Correct on all counts. At least for small allocations, we might expect that `malloc`/`realloc` is doing its own geometric resizing under the hood, because it's using a bucketing technique such as [buddy blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation). See [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48612539/1424877) which I just posted on the subject (having found no suitable code already); you can use that code to test the behavior of realloc on your platform of choice and see whether it's doing the Nice Thing here.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I never thought of using call backs to apply the Single Responsibility Principle. I have tried to implement this in my [next program] (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187413/c-program-implementing-a-simple-test-framework/187499#187499)

Answer (score 4):

Some ideas better as an answer than a comment

A weakness with `rc = str_cat(logbuf, errmes, NULL);` is at least conceptual - code is calling a failing function. Code is in an error handler of the function `str_cat()` and there is something wrong for who-knows-what core reason. Calling `str_cat()` again is risky. Better to get the error message out first.

If `snprintf()` is not available, using an generous  right-sized buffer rather than a magic number 100 is prudent, one based on the size of the format and it *worst-case*  arguments.  Example: with `long` as 64-bit,  `111` was needed in your code (see following).   IMO, a *generous  buffer* is 2x whatever you think it might be.

```
string copy failed : source length 18446744073709551615 >           dest allocated space 18446744073709551615
```

---

Rather than

```
    char errmes[100];
    sprintf(errmes, "string copy failed : source length %lu > \
        dest allocated space %lu\n", (unsigned long)sourcelen, \
        (unsigned long)dest->size);
```

Consider

```
    #define ERR_STR_CPY "string copy failed : source length %lu > \
        dest allocated space %lu\n"
    // /3 is about log10(2)
    #define ULONG_DECIMAL_LEN (sizeof(unsigned long)*CHAR_BITS/3 + 2)
    #define ERR_STR_CPY_N (sizeof ERR_STR_CPY + 2*ULONG_DECIMAL_LEN)
    char errmes[ERR_STR_CPY_N*2];
    sprintf(errmes, ERR_STR_CPY, (unsigned long)sourcelen, (unsigned long)dest->size);
```

---

It is unclear, perhaps a mistake, that OP put so many spaces in the format below

```
    // long format?
    sprintf(errmes, "string copy failed : source length %lu > \
        dest allocated space %lu\n", (unsigned long)sourcelen, \
        (unsigned long)dest->size); 

    // wanted format?
    sprintf(errmes, "string copy failed : source length %lu > " 
        "dest allocated space %lu\n", (unsigned long)sourcelen, 
        (unsigned long)dest->size);
```

That is why programmer computed magic numbers like 100 vs. program computed values are risky.

Comment: Btw, I learned the other day that [GCC has a secret hidden feature that will find all these format-string bugs for you: `-Wformat-overflow=2 -Wformat-truncation=2`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hh2YEwYT9vH4jSwp). Unfortunately these options are *not* part of `-W -Wall -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-security -pedantic`; you have to find out about them by word of mouth. :/ Anyway, `-Wformat-overflow=2` does indeed complain about a couple of places in OP's code.

Comment: @Quuxplusone "-Wformat-overflow=2 -Wformat-truncation=2" --> very interesting.  FWIW, the biggest issue I have about `snprintf()` is the lack of error handling employed when the buffer was truncated.  Sure, the array did not overrun, but its contents are certainly problematic.  `snprintf(command, 12, "%s", "erase drive not");`  "-Wformat-truncation=2"` can help.  Thanks

Comment: I don't consider truncation a huge problem *usually*, and when it is, can't you just do `int written = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "fmt"...); if (written >= sizeof buf) report_error(); else trust(buf);`? Anyway, I bet we agree that "biggest issues" are relative. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Lots of good ideas from yourself and @Quuxplusone but I need some time to digest them

Comment: @Quuxplusone  `snprintf()` returns a negative on encoding error also.  Yes, `int written = snprintf(..); if (written >= sizeof buf)` is usually good enough to wrap negatives as hoped and catch both encoding error and truncation.