# C program implementing a simple test framework

Tags: c, unit-testing

I have written a template for a C program implementing a simple test framework.

If the program is run with the first parameter "test", all subsequent parameters will be interpreted as a sequence of test cases (without the `test_` prefix) to be executed. If no other parameters are specified after the first parameter "test", all functions named `test_*` will be executed in the sequence specified in the `TEST_CASES` macro.

If one of the test cases fails, the program will report this and stop. In no test case fails, `All test cases completed successfully` will be logged.

Normally I would split the program into a header, general function definitions and test case files, but for SE, I thought it would be easier post the amalgamated code.

What do you think?

```
/*template.c - program template with a basic test framework*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*To add a new test case for function foo(), add a line "X(foo) \" to the 
  TEST_CASES macro and then define the concrete test case function as -
  result_t *test_foo(result_t *result){
// Code to test foo() goes here. If the test is successful, set 
// result->rc = SUCCESS. Messages should be added to result->string using 
// the cat_message function
}
*/
#define TEST_CASES \
  X(init_string) \
X(cat_message) \
X(parse_tc) \
X(get_all_tc)

/*Return codes*/
typedef enum {
  SUCCESS,
  ERR_MALLOC,
  ERR_REALLOC,
  ERR_GENERAL
} rc_t;

/*String object : array of char with allocated size*/
typedef struct {
  size_t size;
  char *str;
} string_t;

/*Test results object : string object with return code*/
typedef struct {
  string_t *string;
  rc_t rc;
} result_t;

/*tc_func_t : test case function signature */
typedef result_t *(*tc_func_t)(result_t *result);

/*Test case execution sequence*/
typedef struct {
  int num_tc; /* number in test cases in the tc_funcs array */
  tc_func_t *tc_funcs; /*pointer to an array of test case functions*/
} tc_seq_t;

/*report_func_t : report results function signature*/
typedef rc_t (*report_func_t)(result_t *result);

/*Function prototypes*/
/*Initialise string object */
string_t *init_string(size_t size);
/*Concatenate a message to the string object*/
string_t *cat_message(const char *message, string_t *string);
/*Count number of test cases in TEST_CASES*/
int count_tc(void);
/*Create a test case set from the command line parameters*/
tc_seq_t *parse_tc(int argc, char **argv);
/*Create a test case set with all test cases specified in the TEST_CASES macro*/
tc_seq_t *get_all_tc(void);
/*Run all test cases in the test case sequence and report results*/
result_t *run_tests(tc_seq_t *tc_seq, report_func_t report_func, 
    result_t *result);
/*Write results to STDOUT*/
rc_t print_stdout(result_t *result);
/*Test case prototypes are generated by the X macro expansion*/
#define X(name) result_t *test_ ## name(result_t *result);
TEST_CASES
#undef X

string_t *init_string(size_t size){
  string_t *string = malloc(sizeof *string);
  /*If an error occurs, return a NULL pointer*/
  if (string == NULL) return NULL;
  string->str = malloc(size);
  if (string->str == NULL){
    free(string);
    return NULL;
  }
  string->size = size;
  *string->str = '\0';
  return string;
}

string_t *cat_message(const char *message, string_t *string){
  /*If the caller does supply the correct parameters, return the string object 
   * unchanged*/
  if (message == NULL || string == NULL || string->str == NULL) return string;
  while (strlen(message) >= string->size - strlen(string->str)){
    /*If the memory allocated to the string object is insufficient, keep 
     * doubling the allocation until it is enough to concancenate the message*/
    string->str = realloc(string->str, string->size * 2);
    if (string->str == NULL) return string; 
    string->size *= 2;
  }
  memcpy(string->str+strlen(string->str), message, strlen(message)+1);
  return string;
}

int count_tc(void){
  int num_tc = 0;
#define X(name) num_tc++;
  TEST_CASES
#undef X
    return num_tc;
}

tc_seq_t *parse_tc(int argc, char **argv){
  /*If the first parameter is not "test", return a NULL pointer*/
  if (argc == 1 || strcmp(argv[1], "test")) return NULL;
  /*if the first and only parameter is "test", return all test cases */
  if (argc == 2) return get_all_tc();
  /*return test cases specified in the parameters after "test"*/
  tc_seq_t *tc_set = malloc(sizeof *tc_set);
  tc_set->tc_funcs = malloc((argc - 2) * sizeof *tc_set->tc_funcs);
  /*If an error occurs, return a NULL pointer*/
  if (tc_set->tc_funcs == NULL) {
    free(tc_set);
    return NULL;
  }
  int tc_ind = 0;
  /*Fill the array testcase->tc_funcs[] with pointers to test functions*/
  for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++){
#define X(name) if (!strcmp(argv[i], #name)) \
    {tc_set->tc_funcs[tc_ind] = test_ ## name; tc_ind++; break;}
    TEST_CASES
#undef X
  }
  tc_set->num_tc = argc - 2;
  return tc_set;
}

tc_seq_t *get_all_tc(void){
  tc_seq_t *tc_set = malloc(sizeof *tc_set);
  if (tc_set == NULL) return NULL;
  tc_set->tc_funcs = malloc(count_tc() * sizeof *tc_set->tc_funcs);
  /*If an error occurs, return a NULL pointer*/
  if (tc_set->tc_funcs == NULL) {
    free(tc_set);
    return NULL;
  }
  tc_set->num_tc = count_tc();
  /*Fill the array testcase->tc_funcs[] with pointers to test functions*/
  int tc = -1;
#define X(name) tc++; tc_set->tc_funcs[tc] = test_ ## name;
  TEST_CASES
#undef X
    return tc_set;
}

result_t *run_tests(tc_seq_t *tc_seq, report_func_t report_func, 
    result_t *result){
  for (int tc_ind = 0; tc_ind < tc_seq->num_tc; tc_ind++) {
    result = tc_seq->tc_funcs[tc_ind](result);
    if (result->rc != SUCCESS) break;
  }
  if (result->rc == SUCCESS) cat_message(
      "All test cases completed successfully\n", result->string);
  free(tc_seq->tc_funcs);
  free(tc_seq);
  report_func(result);
  return result;
}

rc_t print_stdout(result_t *result){
  if (result == NULL) return ERR_GENERAL;
  if (result->string == NULL) return ERR_GENERAL;
  if (result->string->str == NULL) return ERR_GENERAL;
  printf("%s", result->string->str);
  printf("Return code: %d\n", result->rc);
  return SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  string_t *string = init_string(1024);
  if (string == NULL) return ERR_MALLOC;
  string = cat_message("Start log\n", string);
  if (string == NULL) return ERR_REALLOC;
  result_t *result = malloc(sizeof *result);
  if (result == NULL) { 
    free(string->str);
    free(string);
    return ERR_GENERAL;
  } 
  result->string = string;
  result->rc = SUCCESS;
  tc_seq_t *tc_seq = parse_tc(argc, argv);
  if (tc_seq != NULL) result = run_tests(tc_seq, print_stdout, result);
  free(string->str);
  free(string);
  free(result);
}

result_t *test_init_string(result_t *result){
  string_t *string = init_string(10);
  if (string == NULL){
    result->rc = ERR_MALLOC;
    result->string = cat_message("init_string failed\n", result->string);
    return result;
  }
  if (string->size == 10 && !strcmp(string->str, "")){
    result->rc = SUCCESS;
  } else {
    result->rc = ERR_GENERAL;
    result->string = cat_message("init_string failed\n", result->string);
  }
  free(string->str);
  free(string);
  return result;
}

result_t *test_cat_message(result_t *result){
  string_t *string = init_string(10);
  if (string == NULL){
    result->rc = ERR_MALLOC;
    return result;
  }
  string = cat_message("foo", string);
  if (string == NULL){
    result->rc = ERR_REALLOC;
    result->string = cat_message("cat_message failed\n", result->string);
    return result;
  }
  string = cat_message("bar", string);
  if (string == NULL){
    result->string = cat_message("cat_message failed\n", result->string);
    result->rc = ERR_REALLOC;
    return result;
  }
  if (string->size == 10 && !strcmp(string->str, "foobar")){
    result->rc = SUCCESS;
  } else {
    result->string = cat_message("cat_message failed\n", result->string);
    result->rc = ERR_GENERAL;
  }
  free(string->str);
  free(string);
  return result;
}

result_t *test_parse_tc(result_t *result){
  char *argv[] = {"template", "test", "parce_tc", "get_all_tc"};
  tc_seq_t *tc = parse_tc(4, argv);
  if (tc == NULL){
    result->string = cat_message("parse_tc failed\n", result->string);
    result->rc = ERR_GENERAL;
    return result;
  }
  if (tc->num_tc == 2) {
    result->rc = SUCCESS;
  } else {
    result->rc = ERR_GENERAL;
    result->string = cat_message("parse_tc failed\n", result->string);
  }
  free(tc->tc_funcs);
  free(tc);
  return result;
}

result_t *test_get_all_tc(result_t *result){
  tc_seq_t *tc = get_all_tc();
  if (tc == NULL){
    result->rc = ERR_GENERAL;
    result->string = cat_message("get_all_tc failed\n", result->string);
    return result;
  }
  if (tc->num_tc == count_tc()) {
    result->rc = SUCCESS;
  } else {
    result->rc = ERR_GENERAL;
    result->string = cat_message("get_all_tc failed\n", result->string);
  }
  free(tc->tc_funcs);
  free(tc);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Something I often do when posting as a single file is to write an empty comment line `<!-- -->` at each file break.  This makes it easy to copy+paste into a file, but still leaves it clear where the boundaries are.

Answer (score 1):

> What do you think?

Well laid out consistently, but a bit tight.
Good basic error handling.
Good uses of `sizeof *obj` in allocation calculations.
Good used of `(void)` with such function declarations.
Compiled well without warnings.

---

### Interface unclear

Certainly the comment was meant to be "... caller does **not** supply ..."

When `cat_message()` returns, how to determine it it succeeded or failed given:
 "If the caller does supply the correct parameters, return the string object 
   * unchanged"?
Recommended to return an error flag, value or `bool`.

### Name space

Functions names `init_string()`, `cat_message()`, `count_tc()` and others share little to hint that they work together.  Recommend a common prefix.

### Doubling unclear.

In `cat_message()`, why repetitively call `realloc()` if code can determine the minimal needs? Just allocate once: maximum of *2x former size* and *size needed*.

### Inefficientcy

In `cat_message()`, code re-calculates `strlen(string->str)` and `strlen(message)` incurring a run down each string.  Just save the lengths and re-use.  Specifically the `strlen(string->str)` is an issue as code may have called `realloc()` and code cannot assume the 2nd call to `strlen(string->str)` returns the same length.

---

Minor

### 0 corner

`init_string(0)` leads to UB due to `*string->str = '\0';`.  Suggest code gracefully handle this corner.  Maybe return `NULL`.

### unsigned math wrap-around

Watch out for underflow of unsigned math with `size_t`.  Both below should work for OP, yet the 2nd form is more resilient to unexpected `string->size`, `string->str` pairs.

```
// while (strlen(message) >= string->size - strlen(string->str))
while (strlen(message) + strlen(string->str) >= string->size )
```

### Assumption

Code assumes `argc == 0` never occurs and so `argv[1]` is not guarded.

```
// if (argc == 1 || strcmp(argv[1], "test")) return NULL;
if (argc <= 1 || strcmp(argv[1], "test")) return NULL;
```

---

Later.

### Information hiding

Code does not detail what might be the `*.h` part and implementation part.  To this end:

```
typedef struct {
  size_t size;
  char *str;
} string_t;
```

and the other 3 `typedef`s only need to declare the pointer type with `typedef struct string_t *string_t;` and then declare the functions.   The definition of the type can occurs later and not in the public `*.h` section.

### How many `rc_t`?

Often code needs to assess the range of an enumerated type.  Useful to add a `_N` as the last one.

```
/*Return codes*/
typedef enum {
  SUCCESS,
  ERR_MALLOC,
  ERR_REALLOC,
  ERR_GENERAL,
  ERR_N    // add
} rc_t;
```

## Non-unique error messages

`cat_message("cat_message failed\n", result->string);` used 3 times.  Maybe `cat_message("cat_message failed 1\n", result->string);`, etc. to help distinguish reported error.

Comment: thanks @chux 1. yes, I missed the word "not" from the comment at the start of cat_message 2. I agree a shared name prefix would be useful for these functions. 3. In hindsight, I see the repetitive `realloc` is inefficient - I should realloc at least `strlen(string->str) + strlen(message)` 4. I assumed the compiler would optimise away the repeated `strlen(x)` calls but I agree, they should not there in the first place. 5. `init_string(0)` does not make sense, I will check `size > 0`. 6. You say watch out for underflow, how could this happen with my `while(...)` expression?

Comment: 7.  I thought argv[0] was always the name of the executable so isn't argc always >= 1? 8. I was going put all code above `string_t *init_string(size_t size){` in a header file since these declarations are used by the internal interfaces of the program, why is this not advisable? 8. I always put ERR_GENERAL in the last position of the `enum` declaration. 9. I agree error messages should be unique.

Comment: @user2309803 3: Off by 1, realloc at least `strlen(string->str) + strlen(message) + 1` 4 Compiler cannot optimize away 2nd `strlen(string->str)` as `string->str` may have changed. 6. Unexpected `string->size, string->str` pairs could result from broken code.

Comment: @user2309803  7 `argc always >= 1` no.  It may be 0.  C spec: "The value of argc shall be nonnegative."  8. Not advisable as it is not needed for public to see it and potential mess with it (see # 6) or write code that depends on it.  8. I was speaking of `enum` declarations in general.

Comment: you could add a subsection "Potential execution of NULL function pointers", To avoid undefined behaviour, there should be a check that `tc_funcs[tc_ind]` and `report_func` are not NULL pointers before execution,  agree?

Comment: @user2309803 Re: testing parameters.  For test code, robust testing of parameters is a very good idea.  For code-under-test, if that code tests parameters or not is a design decision.  The more complex the code-under-test, the more testing of parameters it should do. AFAIK, you can post this as an answer, even is you are the OP.